# Casting null to void array

Tags: java, android

What is the effect of casting `null` to `Void[]`? I haven't seen it before, I came across it while reading `LoaderThrottle` example [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/LoaderThrottle.java#456).

```
 mPopulatingTask.executeOnExecutor(
                            AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, (Void[])null);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the answer of @CommonsWare imagine the following scenario:

```
public void doStuff(SomeType type) {
    ...
}

public void doStuff(OtherType type) {
    ...
}
```

You have two methods with the same signature, only the type of the parameters are different.

Now if you were to call `doStuff(null);` the compiler would have no clue as to which method it should use here and gives you a `Ambiguous method call`. With `doStuff((OtherType)null);` you remove the ambiguity and the compiler is happy.

Comment: Thanks @QBrute got it.

Answer (score 2):

In general, if there are multiple possible types for that second parameter, the cast tells the compiler which candidate type should be used for the `null`.

In this specific case, that second parameter should be superfluous, as `executeOnExecutor()` takes an `Executor` and then a varargs, and zero parameters is perfectly valid for a varargs.